# Why valence electron to atom ratio affect stacking fault energy?

Tags: material-science, metals, granulated-materials

Wikipedia [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacking-fault_energy) on factors that affect the stacking-fault energy (SFE) of a material says:

> Another factor that has a significant effect on the SFE of a material and is very interrelated with alloy content is the e/a ratio, or the ratio of valence electrons to atoms. Thornton showed this in 1962 by plotting the e/a ratio vs SFE for a few Cu based alloys. He found that the valence-electron to atom ratio is a good predictor of stacking fault energy, even when the alloying element is changed. This directly supports the graphs on the right. Zinc is a heavier element and only has two valence electrons, whereas aluminum is lighter and has three valence electrons. Thus each weight percent of aluminum has a much greater impact on the SFE of the Cu-based alloy than does zinc.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

So, my question is why does the e/a ratio of electrons to atoms affect the SFE?

Comment: First, showing the plots in weight % rather than atomic % makes it harder to compare, for sure, and the scaling is not really that great from Al to Zn based on e/a. As to why it changes things, consider the Fermi surface and the available free electrons, and how they would impact screening around dislocations.

Comment: I am kind of beginner in material science. So, it would br better if you elaborate. @Jon Custer